# Android: Disabling Text Scaling (keeping sp the same as dp)?

Tags: android, text, graphics, scaling

I'm working on an app that is (supposed to be) device-specific (theoretically always used on a Nexus 7, though it may be either version of that device). Many of the Views will contain some combination of text and graphics, positioned in ways that are meaningful. If I use "sp" to define text sizes as recommended, and the user globally changes the "text size", the text will be scaled but the graphics will not - completely destroying the visual presentation.

I want to use dp instead of hard pixel units because the different versions of the Nexus 7 have different display densities. It would also be nice if the positional relationships were maintained if, say, somebody changes their mind and the app gets run on some other display. dp handles this for graphics, but by having a different measurement unit for text it allows the overall presentation to be damaged by the user.

Is there a way to disable the scaling that is optionally applied to "sp", so that the relationships between graphics (defined with dp) and text (defined with sp) can't be corrupted? Frankly, I'd like to just define the text with dp but can't find a way using code to do so (none of the TypedValue constants seem to support it).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you creating your views dynamically? I think you can use dp for text size in xml it just isn't the best practice. Not 100% though

Comment: Yes, the Views are created in code and can change during execution. That's why I included the comment about TypedValue, since that's how you specify units to TextView.setTextSize().

Comment: I figured based on that, but I didn't know if they had to be :)

Answer (score 1):

> If I use "sp" to define text sizes as recommended, and the user globally changes the "text size", the text will be scaled but the graphics will not - completely destroying the visual presentation.

User-controlled font scaling has been around for a long time in desktop GUIs, and came to prominence in Web design with user-controlled font scaling in browsers. Perhaps you might consider learning how to handle the text size changes, the way countless developers did before you.

> Frankly, I'd like to just define the text with dp but can't find a way using code to do so (none of the TypedValue constants seem to support it).

`dp` is also abbreviated `dip` and stands for density-independent pixels. The corresponding [`TypedValue` is `COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP).

Comment: Yes, I know how it works for web pages and the like. But this is a integrated graphics+text environment. An analogy would be a car's dash display. How would you "handle the text size changes"? How would it look if the numbers/letters changed size? As just one example, consider if the numbers around the speedo or tach increased by 3X; their positions relative to the tick marks on the gauge would fail. But you might want to make them dynamic to accommodate different units of measure and/or full scale ranges. You can't have canned clipart to anticipate every possibility.

Comment: That tip about COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP is very helpful, thanks. I will investigate that.

Comment: @AndroidNewbie: "their positions relative to the tick marks on the gauge would fail" -- talented programmers anchor the labels to the tick marks.

Comment: @AndroidNewbie: Or, don't use individual widgets for any of this, and draw the image and the labels on the canvas. In either case, choosing the spot for the labels based upon the current text size is eminently doable. After all, text size is not merely a function of font size, but language as well.

Comment: "talented programmers anchor the labels to the tick marks." But if one is scaling and the other is not, their visual relationship will still be changing and ruin the visual presentation.